# How can I concatenate arrays in liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

This kind of Q&A was exist before but there was anything fit with mine. 
I want to concatenate arrays in liquid within empty array and array

**array1**
`subject = ''`
**array2**
`tsubject = ["appple", "pine appeld"]`
**array what I want to get**
`["appple", "pine appeld"]`

to combine this I tried

```rb
{% assign subject = '' %}
{% for post in site.programming %}
  {% assign tsubjects = post.categories %}
  {% assign subject=subject | append: tsubjects %}
{% endfor %}
```

```rb
{% assign subject = '' %}
{% for post in site.programming %}
  {% assign tsubjects = post.categories %}
  {% subject=subject | concat: tsubjects %} 
{% endfor %}
```

but nothing changed, subject was still empty.
I think this is because of `concat`, `concat` concatenate array shapes like this:
`{% assign vegetables = "broccoli, carrots, lettuce, tomatoes" | split: ", " %}`
But I want concatenate below type:
`{% assign vegetables = ["broccoli", "carrots", "lettuce", "tomatoes"] | split: ", " %}`
I'm not sure about reason why they don't work. please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing **string/array** values and filters.

```
{% assign subject = '' %}
subject : {{ subject | inspect }} "" <== String

{% assign subject = '' | split: '' %}
subject : {{ subject | inspect }} [] <== Array
```

If you want to make an array from all categories in programming collection, you must [concat](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/concat/) two arrays, and it can be something like :

```
{% comment %} --- Creates an empty array {% endcomment %}
{% assign subject = '' | split: '' %}

{% comment %} --- Debug output {% endcomment %}
subject : {{ subject | inspect }}

{% for post in site.programming %}
  {% assign tsubjects = post.categories %}

  {% comment %} --- Just to be sure that there is something in post.categories {% endcomment %}
  tsubjects : {{ tsubjects | inspect }}

  {% assign subject=subject | concat: tsubjects %}

  {% comment %} --- Debug output {% endcomment %}
  concat : {{ subject | inspect }}

{% endfor %}

{% comment %} --- Makes sure that values are unique {% endcomment %}
{% assign subject = subject | uniq %}
uniq : {{ subject | inspect }}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Now I get difference between assigning string and array. Thanks it works now! now I'll try counting if there is same categories so that how many post exist in each category